# ¿Como contar los caracteres distintos a cierto carácter al momento de leer un archivo? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, archivo, matrices, split

Lo que pasa es que tengo un archivo `.txt`, el cual tiene una matriz de letras, pero las letras se encuentran separadas solo por coma, por lo que me gustaría solo contar cuantas letras hay de manera que no se incluyan las comas en el contador.

[image: Contenido del archivo]

Por ejemplo en este caso me gustaría que hubiera un contador de letras, el cual se aumentara cada vez que lea un carácter que no sea (`,`) por lo que hagamos de ejemplo esta misma matriz, la cual la variable contador tendría que ser igual a 16, ya que las letras son 16, por ahora solo he podido codificar la parte de leer el texto completo, mas no tengo idea de como hacer solo para contar las letras, he estado investigando y quizá la función `split` pueda ayudar a separar comas de letras, mas sin embargo no tengo idea de como codificarlo.

```
 public static void leerArchivo() {

    String dato;

    try {
        File archivo = new File(eliminar.txt);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(archivo);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            dato = myReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(dato);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }


}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal eliminar las comas ([replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))) y luego contar la cantidad de caracteres en cada línea ([length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()))?

Comment: ¿Tendría que reemplazar las comas por ""(espacios sin nada) no?

Answer (score 1):

Una opción podría ser usar un **FileReader** para leer el archivo junto con el método **read()** para ir leyendo carácter a carácter (ojo, que read() lee como int) e ir aumentando el valor del contador **discriminando los caracteres que no quieres que cuenten** (no sólo la coma, tienes que tener también en cuenta los espacios, retrocesos, saltos de línea...):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File archivo = new File("caracteres.txt");
        
        System.out.println("El archivo tiene " + contarLetrasDeArchivo(archivo) + " letras");
    }
    
    public static int contarLetrasDeArchivo(File archivo){
        
        int contador = 0;

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            
            int caracter = fr.read();
            
            while(caracter != -1){
                if((caracter != 44) && (caracter != 13) && (caracter != 32) && (caracter != 9) && (caracter != 10)){
                    contador++;
                }
                caracter = fr.read();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjercicioLeerTextoYContarCaracteres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjercicioLeerTextoYContarCaracteres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return contador;
   } 
}
```

Salida:

```
El archivo tiene 16 letras
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda, compañero.